# Crash on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, crash

Can anyone help with any hints by looking into following iPhone device crash log why is the app is getting crashed at the startup itself?

Note: App crashes not all time it does only 50% times of app launch.
Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
Date/Time:       2011-03-21 19:15:21.363 +0000

OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)

Report Version:  104


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x736f485b

Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00003f24 objc_msgSend + 24

1   UIKit                           0x0002ff18 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128

2   UIKit                           0x000ff538 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 128

3   CoreFoundation                  0x00049a3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20

4   UIKit                           0x0015d968 -[UIApplication sendAction:fromSender:toTarget:forEvent:] + 132

5   UIKit                           0x0019a1dc -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 48

6   UIKit                           0x000e6a68 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 520

7   UIKit                           0x0019af68 -[UIControl mouseUp:] + 500

8   UIKit                           0x00171fbc -[UIView(Internal) _mouseUp:] + 52

9   UIKit                           0x0016cb8c -[UIWindow _handleMouseUp:] + 164

10  UIKit                           0x0016d144 -[UIWindow _statusBarMouseUp:] + 184

11  UIKit                           0x0035e768 -[UIStatusBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 436

12  CoreFoundation                  0x00049a3c -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20

13  UIKit                           0x00030160 forwardMethod2 + 72

14  UIKit                           0x00021ea8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 580

15  UIKit                           0x000214dc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 388

16  UIKit                           0x00004c94 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 444

17  UIKit                           0x000043ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6816

18  GraphicsServices                0x00005c80 PurpleEventCallback + 1040

19  CoreFoundation                  0x000365c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22

20  CoreFoundation                  0x00036582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158

21  CoreFoundation                  0x0002882e __CFRunLoopRun + 574

22  CoreFoundation                  0x00028504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220

23  CoreFoundation                  0x00028412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54

24  GraphicsServices                0x00004d1c GSEventRunModal + 188

25  UIKit                           0x0004a574 -[UIApplication _run] + 580

26  UIKit                           0x00047550 UIApplicationMain + 964

27  checkmate                       0x00002bbe main + 74

28  checkmate                       0x00002b34 start + 44
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code that's causing the crash?

Comment: What does **your** debugger say when it crashes?

Comment: Check the blog tutorial for reading and finding the exact line in code causing crash. [IPhone Crash Logs](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/) [symbolicate iphone crash](http://www.google.com/search?q=symbolicate%20iphone%20crash)

Comment: Seems odd that stack crawl has a lot of touch handling calls. Sure this is during startup and no because you tap something?

Comment: The stack crawl only contains iOS internal addresses.

Comment: Kindly paste the code. That should help.

Comment: @Claus Broch : plz read the first link.

Comment: Yes, but the posted stackcrawl still doesn't contain any references to app code (with the exception of the main() function). All ather entries are in iOS library code.

Comment: I know nothing about the iPhone, but doesn't this line (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) tell you to give others the code?

Comment: Do check out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958307/app-crashing-with-this-error-message-i-cannot-find-anything-about-this-after-g

Answer (score 0):

You try to access an object that is not allocated. Paste the lines where app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably over releasing an object. Activate NSZombies to find out which. See [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/4917557#4917557)