# crash on touching the status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, uistatusbar

My app is Navigation based. UIBarButtonItem on it.

```
refreshstopButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self 
action:@selector(refreshTapped)];
```

I found when I tap on the status bar, "refreshTapped" gets triggered (not caused by my big finger, also reproducible by using simulator and mouse click). Stacktrace shows it comes from

```
-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:];
```

I don't understand why. Sometimes my app crashes with very similar stacktrace as [Crash on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032187/crash-on-iphone)

NOTE:
I also tried UICatalog sample, I saw the same thing: clicking on the status bar triggers the "Back" UIBarButtonItem action (using simulator).

After playing with the simulator for a while, i realized the sensitive area is much bigger than the button border. I think maybe that is the way Cocoa Touch works.

However the crash problem remain unsolved. According to the stacktrace, looks like it's triggered by a touch of the status bar.

Here is the crash log:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32da1cb2 objc_msgSend + 42
1   UIKit                           0x324c3a30 -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 28
2   UIKit                           0x324c3990 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 352
3   UIKit                           0x32563764 -[UIControl mouseUp:] + 376
4   UIKit                           0x3254d314 -[UIView(Internal) _mouseUp:] + 32
5   UIKit                           0x3254a480 -[UIWindow _handleMouseUp:] + 108
6   UIKit                           0x3254a8da -[UIWindow _statusBarMouseUp:] + 122
7   UIKit                           0x32680980 -[UIStatusBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 320
8   CoreFoundation                  0x328d056a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
9   UIKit                           0x32406094 forwardMethod2 + 60
10  UIKit                           0x324a04ca -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 2
11  UIKit                           0x32404bee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
12  UIKit                           0x32404568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
13  UIKit                           0x323ed30c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
14  UIKit                           0x323ecc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
```

I also tried to follow http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html to capture event on status bar. But as some other people pointed out, it no longer works in iOS 4.x

Comment: Post the declaration code of refreshTapped.

Comment: `- (IBAction) refreshTapped {
    if (self.isRefresh == YES) {
        [self requestNetworkActivityIndicator];
        [self performLoading];
        [self releaseNetworkActivityIndicator];        
    }
    else {
        [self.webview stopLoading];
        [self releaseNetworkActivityIndicator];
    }
    }`

Comment: Do you try to comment all code lines in `refreshTapped` method?

Comment: I haven't check but set return type of method (void) refreshTapped, instead of IBAction.

Comment: +Nekto, I guess it will do nothing. And I doubt it's relevant to the crash I see.

Answer (score 0):

Check & Replace this line to avoid crashing problem.

`@selector(refreshTapped:)` instead of  `@selector(refreshTapped)`

(notice the extra `:` in the first alternative)

Comment: He don't need to write `:` because of his method doesn't receive any parameter.